# I2Cdev #include weirdness

Tags: mpu6050

I am using [Jeff Rowberg's MPU6050 library](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050), and I simply don't understand what is going on in the following lines of the first example (MPU6050_raw.ino):

```
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050.h"

// Arduino Wire library is required if I2Cdev I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
// implementation is used in I2Cdev.h
#if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
    #include <Wire.h>
#endif
```

So, what I got from that is, if I2Cdev is using Wire instead of some alternative I2C library, I should include Wire.h. I really don't see why that's necessary, so I removed the line in which Wire.h is included, and got this error:

```
C:\Users\Franco2500k\Documents\Arduino\libraries\I2Cdev/I2Cdev.h:80:26: fatal error: Wire.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Wire.h>
```

So, apparently, I2Cdev.h already tries to include Wire.h, but somehow fails? And another #include a few lines later goes back in time and fixes everything? Can someone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino IDE means well, really it does. It copies your source, the device core, and any libraries used by your source all to a separate directory so that it doesn't poison any of their original locations unintentionally.

But of course, there's something missing from that list. The IDE *doesn't copy libraries used by other libraries*. Therefore if you don't include Wire.h in your .ino file then Wire will be missing from the build and you get the error observed. Cracktastic.

Comment: Indeed. I describe this process here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13178/classes-and-objects-how-many-and-which-file-types-i-actually-need-to-use-them/13182#13182

Comment: Weird. So, if I understood that right, I2Cdev.cpp is not compiled, waiting to be linked; it is instead compiled with the entire project every time I build it, and the IDE knows which sources to compile by scanning the my source for #includes. Is that right?