# Inheritance: error in calling the constructor of the base class?

Tags: class, rgb-led, neopixel

I want to write a library for the RGBDigit shield (http://rgbdigit.com/), which essentially is an Adafruit Neopixel strip, packed as a 7 segment display. The shield also has a DS3231 clock and an IR receiver.

So my plan was to make a class *RGBDigit*, which inherits from the *Adafruit_NeoPixel* class and add private objects *DS3231* and *IRrecv*.

This is my RGBDigit.h:

```c
#ifndef RGBDigit_h
#define RGBDigit_h

#include <Arduino.h>
#include "Wire.h"
#include "../Adafruit_NeoPixel/Adafruit_NeoPixel.h"
#include "../IRremote/IRremote.h"
#include "../DS3231/DS3231.h"

class RGBDigit : public Adafruit_NeoPixel {
    public:
        RGBDigit(int nDigits);
        ~RGBDigit();
    private:
        int _nDigits;
        DS3231 _clock;
        IRrecv* _ir;
};

#endif
```

This is RGBDigit.cpp:

```c
#include "RGBDigit.h"


RGBDigit::RGBDigit(int nDigits)
    : Adafruit_NeoPixel(8 * nDigits, 12, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
    _nDigits(nDigits)
{
    _ir = new IRrecv(10);
    _ir->enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
    Adafruit_NeoPixel::begin();
}

RGBDigit::~RGBDigit()
{
    delete _ir;
}
```

And this is my Arduino sketch:

```c
#include <Wire.h>
#include <RGBDigit.h>

RGBDigit display = RGBDigit(4);

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I get al lot of "undefined reference" errors:

```
RGBDigit/RGBDigit.cpp.o: In function `RGBDigit::RGBDigit(int)':
/home/ralph/Arduino/libraries/RGBDigit/RGBDigit.cpp:23: undefined reference to `Adafruit_NeoPixel::Adafruit_NeoPixel(unsigned int, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
/home/ralph/Arduino/libraries/RGBDigit/RGBDigit.cpp:23: undefined reference to `DS3231::DS3231()'
/home/ralph/Arduino/libraries/RGBDigit/RGBDigit.cpp:25: undefined reference to `IRrecv::IRrecv(int)'
/home/ralph/Arduino/libraries/RGBDigit/RGBDigit.cpp:26: undefined reference to `IRrecv::enableIRIn()'
/home/ralph/Arduino/libraries/RGBDigit/RGBDigit.cpp:27: undefined reference to `Adafruit_NeoPixel::begin()'
RGBDigit/RGBDigit.cpp.o: In function `RGBDigit::~RGBDigit()':
/home/ralph/Arduino/libraries/RGBDigit/RGBDigit.cpp:30: undefined reference to `Adafruit_NeoPixel::~Adafruit_NeoPixel()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But I don' t understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're assuming that the IDE is smart enough to know that it needs to copy over and link the other libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "../Adafruit_NeoPixel/Adafruit_NeoPixel.h"
#include "../IRremote/IRremote.h"
#include "../DS3231/DS3231.h"
```

What you're doing there is telling the *compiler* where, relative to where it's performing the compiling (or one of its include directories), the header files you list are.

What you're *not* doing is telling the *IDE* where the CPP files are to compile and link with your sketch.

When including *anything* external to the sketch folder that is *more* than *just a header file* you *must* treat it as an Arduino library - that is, place it in one of the standard library folders and name it properly (libraries should be named `LibraryName/LibraryName.h`).

Then you include the libraries properly:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <DS3231.h>
```

You must do that in *both* your sketch *and* your custom library.  That way the IDE knows where to look for the files to compile - the compiler doesn't understand the concept of an Arduino library (and thus the CPP files associated with a header file) - that is purely down to the IDE gathering the data by examining your sketch and locating the right files to then pass to the compiler.

Comment: Thank you very much; I understand it now! But isn't it a bad thing that someone who wants to use my RGBDigit library, also needs to know which other classes and libraries are used by RGBDigit?

Comment: @Ralph: With all due credit to the Arduino IDE's developers for a basic download-and-go beginners IDE, it has its limitations. You have met some of them.

Comment: @Ralph Yep, that's a shortcoming all right.  One that I addressed in my replacement IDE - [UECIDE](http://uecide.org).  Upgrade to that and you won't see that problem since it can recursively scan libraries for other libraries that they rely on.

Comment: See [How the IDE organizes things](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/13182/10794) for more details about this. `But isn't it a bad thing that someone who wants to use my RGBDigit library, also needs to know which other classes and libraries are used by RGBDigit?` - most IDEs need you to tell them, one way or another, which libraries to use. If UECIDE does that automatically, that sounds good. However if you rely upon a different IDE, now you need to tell your users that it only works with that IDE. Maybe you could just explain in the documentation you post with it?