# Compilling error not highlighting line in code

Tags: arduino-uno, compile

A newbe here. How come when I compile with an error I do not get the line or line number highlighted? I Get the errors just can't find where they are.

Comment: Because the Arduino "IDE" is a mere toy. If you want real IDE facilities then you need to use a real IDE, not the sub-par text editor that is the Arduino IDE.

Comment: I would also recommend to stop relying on that sort of hints. If you read the error message, you will find out that gcc not only tells you where it encounters the error, it also tells you why there is an error.

Comment: Update your IDE version to 1.6.x . That should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The line in error can often be highlighted, however because of the way the IDE plays with your source file this is not always the case.

See my post about [How the IDE organizes things](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13178/classes-and-objects-how-many-and-which-file-types-i-actually-need-to-use-them).

The IDE adds extra lines to your source, and then tries to hide that with #line directives. This can confuse the way error messages are handled. It is another example of the "helpful" IDE not always being helpful.

In any event, as Igor said, you can look for the line number in the error message and use that to find the error. Failing that, look at the quoted source code and search for that.