# AttachInterrupt - fail to initiate inside a class

Tags: class, isr

I'm trying to create a class that uses `attachInterrupt`, but get this error msg:

```
 In member function 'void ledDoor::attach()':
ClosetLedStrip:31:82: error: invalid use of non-static member function
         attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(_sensorPin), detection_door, CHANGE);
                                                                                  ^
exit status 1
invalid use of non-static member function
```

I found few [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443720/how-to-create-an-isr-in-an-arduino-class) regarding `static member`, but it was not clear for my needs.

Appreciate help,

```
#define USE_SLEEP true

#if USE_SLEEP
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#endif

#define sensorPin_1 2
#define sensorPin_2 3
#define RelayON HIGH
#define doorOpen HIGH

#define pwrdown_timeOut 10*(1000*60) // mins to powerdown

// volatile boolean detectDoor_1_Open = false;
//volatile boolean detectDoor_2_Open = false;
const int relayPin1 = 4;
const int relayPin2 = 5;


class ledDoor {




private:
int _sensorPin;
int _interruptPin;
int _relPin;

void  attach(){
        attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(_sensorPin), detection_door, CHANGE);
}

void detection_door(){
    #if USE_SLEEP
        sleep_disable();
    #endif

        detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(_sensorPin));
        if (digitalRead(_sensorPin) == doorOpen) {
                _doorOpen = true;
        }
        else {// trun off
                _doorOpen = false;
        }
        attach();
}

public:
bool volatile _doorOpen;
ledDoor(int sensorPin, int relPin){
        _sensorPin=sensorPin;
        _relPin=relPin;

        pinMode(_relPin, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(_sensorPin, INPUT); // sensor io
        attach();
}
void go2sleep() {
  #if USE_SLEEP
        sleep_enable();
        set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
        sleep_cpu();
  #endif

}
void switchLeds(){
        if (_doorOpen == true) {
                digitalWrite(_relPin, RelayON);
        }
        else{
                digitalWrite(_relPin, !RelayON);
        }
}

};

ledDoor door1(sensorPin_1, relayPin1);
ledDoor door2(sensorPin_2, relayPin2);

void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);
        Serial.println("UP");    
}


void loop() {
        door1.switchLeds();
        door2.switchLeds();

  #if USE_SLEEP
        door1.go2sleep();
        door2.go2sleep();
  #endif
}
```

Comment: perhaps the reason that you cannot find a satisfactory answer is because you do not ask a question

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, if `detection_door` is a non-static member function, then C++ simply has no such expression syntax as just `detection_door`. Such functions have to either be called (with `()` operator) or be taken address of (with `&` operator). You can't just say `detection_door`. That's meaningless, which is what the compiler is telling you.

Secondly, as you already realized, regardless of the syntax a non-static class member function cannot be used as an interrupt handler. You need a freestanding ("ordinary") function as a handler or a static class member. Non-static class methods are beasts of completely different and incompatible nature.

I see that you have multiple `ledDoor` objects that you want to attach to interrupts independently.

At the level of `attachInterrupt` and `void (void)` handlers you will not be able to use a single interrupt handler function and then properly dispatch the handling to multiple individual objects. The high-level `attachInterrupt` mechanism is insufficient to work around this limitation in a proper way. (At ISR level you can do that, the same way `Servo.h` handles multiple servos, but it is more complicated.)

For this reason, in your case, as long as you want to stay at `attachInterrupt` level, it is better to just implement two separate interrupt handlers as external functions that will call your class methods for your existing global objects

```cpp
ledDoor door1(sensorPin_1, relayPin1);
ledDoor door2(sensorPin_2, relayPin2);

void handler_door1()
{
  door1.detection_door();
}

void handler_door2()
{
  door2.detection_door();
}
```

and then just attach these handlers to your desired pins in a regular way.

`static` in this case can only change things in a purely cosmetic way.

---

On the second thought one can wrap the above into a quasi-elegant implementation that might look as follows

```cpp
constexpr unsigned N_PINS = 16; // Range of attachable pin numbers

class ledDoor 
{
  // ...

  static ledDoor *self[N_PINS];
  static void (*const HANDLERS[N_PINS])();

  template <unsigned PIN> static void handler() 
  { // This is the actual interrupt handler that will dispatch the call to
    // the `detection_door` method of the proper class object
    self[PIN]->detection_door();
  }

  // ...

  void attach()
  {
    self[_sensorPin] = this;
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(_sensorPin), HANDLERS[_sensorPin], CHANGE);
  }

  void detection_door()
  {
    // Your code
  }
};
```

And somewhere in one of the `.cpp` files

```cpp
// Definitions and initializers for static members

ledDoor *ledDoor::self[N_PINS] = {};

void (*const ledDoor::HANDLERS[N_PINS])() = 
{
  ledDoor::handler<0>,
  ledDoor::handler<1>,
  // ...and so on...
  ledDoor::handler<15>
};
```

This uses a dedicated callback for each pin. Maybe a better idea would be to use interrupt number (i.e. the result of `digitalPinToInterrupt`) for indexing instead of pin number.

The same thing can be rewritten through lambdas instead of a template. I.e. one can get rid of `ledDoor::handler<>` template and instead initialize the `HANDLERS` array as

```cpp
void (*const ledDoor::HANDLERS[N_PINS])() = 
{
  [](){ ledDoor::self[0]->detection_door(); },
  [](){ ledDoor::self[1]->detection_door(); },
  // ...and so on...
  [](){ ledDoor::self[15]->detection_door(); }
};
```

Note that this approach is a bit more memory wasteful that it could have been, since it uses a number of static tables of pre-determined size. In essense this is a slightly different implementation of the same "gluing" approach as described [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/20608/pass-classs-public-function-as-an-argument-to-external-command).

Comment: Where do you write ‘AttachInterrupt’?

Comment: @Guy . D: Wherever you are ready to do that. In `setup()`, for example.