# Help: convert Arduino code to avr-gcc code

Tags: arduino-mega, c++, c, avr

I need to convert Arduino code to avr-gcc code. This is code:

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo; 

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(11);
}

void loop() { 
  myservo.write(67);
}
```

I use Arduino Mega.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a "gimme tha codez" site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will a .ino Arduino Sketch compile directly on GCC-AVR?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21492/will-a-ino-arduino-sketch-compile-directly-on-gcc-avr)

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question, you might have asked: "how can I re-implement the servo library in avr-gcc", but that will require quite some effort and a little knowledge from your side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <Servo.h>

extern "C" void init(void);

Servo myservo;

int main()
{
    init();
    myservo.attach(11);
    for (;;) {
        myservo.write(67);
    }
}
```

Note that this still needs the Arduino core library, as the Servo
library depends on it, which means all this is an exercise in futility.
If you are using the Arduino core, the simplest thing is to use it the
Arduino way. If you do not want to use Arduino core, then you will have
to partially re-implement the Servo library.

Comment: @user29971: oops, forgot an include, fixed. Do not forget to add all the relevant `-I`, `-L` and `-l` options to the compile command.

Comment: compiler code in avr-gcc comand line in linux no include Arduino.h include avr/io.h. thanks Edgar Bonet

Comment: i use standard library and registers.

Comment: @user29971: If you do not want to `#include <Arduino.h>`, you can just declare `init()` yourself, see amended answer.