# is #ifdef __SD_H__ considered a bad practice?

Tags: programming, library, c-preprocessor

Say I'm working on a library<sup>^**1**</sup> to which I want to add support for `SD.h`<sup>^**2**</sup> but knowing for a fact that many microcotrollers don't support `SD.h` *(therefore they result in compilation errors [eg. Attiny85])* I don't want to just `#include <SD.h>` *(or even `#ifndef __SD_H__` then `#include <SD.h>`)* in `Mylibrary.h` and make it totally unusable for some microcontrollers. So I was wondering, is it considered ok to just add the functionality like...

```cpp
// Mylibrary.h

#ifdef __SD_H__
    // Save functionality for those including `SD.h` to their `sketch.ino`
    void Mylibrary::save(String filename){
        SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE)
        // ...
    }
#endif
```

...without ever including the `SD.h` in `Mylibrary.h` and hence force the user whenever he\she wants to use some SD functionallity, to just include `SD.h` in his\her `sketch.ino`?  **+***(it sound exhausting to do something like [this](https://github.com/GiorgosXou/NeuralNetworks/blob/31bb95e4cefcaefb28f6b031a634ded6c7274a7d/src/NeuralNetwork.h#L52-L55) for every MCU, as an alternative way)*

<sup>[**1**] *(in my case [this library](https://github.com/GiorgosXou/NeuralNetworks))*
[**2**] *(in my case  something related to [this](https://github.com/GiorgosXou/NeuralNetworks/issues/18#issuecomment-1792298022))*

**PS.** The reason I'm asking is because I don't remember seeing it anywhere being used that way and I'm slightly confused as to if this is the right or wrong thing to do so</sup>

Comment: [Chat-GPT says it's reasonable](https://chat.openai.com/share/67507088-d6bf-44ce-b3b8-ec6c78b68e50), but I really want to know your thoughts about how would you approach such an issue

Comment: Do not trust ChatGPT, always assume it is hallucinating.

Comment: It is bad and I have seen it :)

Comment: Note that identifiers that start with two underscores (or one underscore and a capital letter) [are reserved](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3): "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

Comment: Since you asked ChatGPT, I asked it as well: "in C++ is it good practice to put all of your code in a .h file?" And the answer was: "No, it is not considered good practice to put all of your code in a .h (header) file in C++. In C++, code is typically organized into header files and source files, and there are specific conventions for what should go in each type of file."  So no, putting all your code (declarations and definitions, that is, function prototypes and implementations) is not considered good practice. You can search other parts of the Internet for other opinions on that.

Comment: @NickGammon, When I started building this library, there wasn't ChatGPT available. Based on my research *(and sure also empirically)* that's what I found out that it was working. Also, I once had them seperate I later decided that I had to merge them into the `.h` for the sake of better MACRO optimization

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is in general a bad practice to use include guard define to detect if the header file is included. It will work only in a header file in a compilation unit which includes the detected header file.

In Arduino all ino files of the sketch are one compilation unit. But every C or C++ file is a separate compilations unit. They would not 'see' the include guard from an include in the ino file(s).

If you want to use the include guard define, don't relay on it exclusively. Use your own define and set it if you detect the include guard. This way user can set it if theirs SD library has a different name for the include guard.

```
#ifdef __SD_H__
#define XY_USE_SD_LIB
#endif

#ifdef XY_USE_SD_LIB
    // Save functionality for those including `SD.h` to their `sketch.ino`
    void Mylibrary::save(String filename){
        SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE)
        // ...
    }
#endif
```

I use this in my popular ArduinoOTA library [here](https://github.com/JAndrassy/ArduinoOTA/blob/5f838871e213474e7dabf70f2ddfc5ecb6cb971a/src/ArduinoOTA.h#L121).

There is other way to detect includes and it works across compilation units, but it doesn't work on all Arduino platforms. It is the `__has_include` 'directive'. I use it [here](https://github.com/JAndrassy/TelnetStream/blob/6005d8d917ee64a80417bae5b4b964cf7a6b3726/src/NetTypes.h#L42).

Comment: That's so cool! clever one! It's exactly what i was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: you are fast :-). please read the last paragraph for an alternative

Comment: That's so interesting I didn't know about `__has_include`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will work, however you could try it and see. Just set the board type to something that doesn't support SD.h.

My problem would be that your library is a separate compilation unit (ie. file) that would be compiled against the things *you* put as header files.

If your library user uses SD.h in the main .ino file, then your library (which is compiled separately) would not know about that. In other words, it wouldn't know whether or not to *implement* the Mylibrary::save function.

I think a fairly simple solution would be to put a define in the include file for your library, eg.

```
#define USE_FILE_SAVING false
```

Then check that in your code. You don't need a whole list of MCUs, just inform the user that if they want file saving implemented to change that one line.

---

For more information see [How the IDE organizes things](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/13182/10794)

Comment: Thanks! it's really interesting though, I also just realised that it depened if it works or not based on which board i select (eg. on arduino uno works, with espressif's ESP32 it doesn't consider that `SD.h` is already defined)

Comment: Wait It's so weird, it copiles just fine on both boards but with ESP32 the `#ifdef __SD_H__ #pragma message("YES SD.h") #else #pragma message("NO SD.h") #endif ` says "No ..."

Comment: Adding SD.h to your main project is not  going to affect how your library compiles. That is a separate compilation unit and does not look at what includes you have in your .ino file. See: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/13182/10794

Comment: [It actually does effect in some cases *(eg. with Arduino UNO)*](https://s5.gifyu.com/images/S8aAm.gif)

Comment: @GiorgosXou This isn't a library, though, right? Of course it affects a *compilation unit*. You are showing in that GIF that putting the include inside a file in a compilation unit (that is, the file we are looking at) will of course affect how that file is compiled. But if you put that include in file A it won't affect  how file B (your library) is compiled.

Comment: Your library is compiled separately (in another compilation) from your .INO file. The library cannot know what includes you may or may not have put in your .INO file.

Comment: [My whole library is in the `.h` file](https://github.com/GiorgosXou/NeuralNetworks/blob/master/src/NeuralNetwork.h). There are no seperate `cpp` files, I just organise each class implementation with [`#pragma region file.cpp`](https://github.com/GiorgosXou/NeuralNetworks/blob/master/src/NeuralNetwork.h#L570C1-L570C33) inside the `.h` *(for the exact reason of extreme macro optimization)*

Comment: *"The library cannot know what includes you may or may not have put in your .INO file."* in many cases like `#ifdef __SD_H__` it knows, in other cases like [@juraj said](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/94745/77085) you have to use `__has_include` like `#if defined __has_include #if __has_include(<SD.h>) #include <SD.h> ...`. But from what I understand, you shouldn't 100% only depend on those

Comment: OK, so the whole library is in a .h file? Then rather than asking whether it will work or not (which you can find out for yourself empirically) how about telling us whether or not it works, and if not, ask us why not?

Comment: I thought I made it clear, I even had a comment `// Mylibrary.h` on my code snippet. I didn't ask "whether it will work or not", I asked  ["how would you approach such an issue"](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/94743/is-ifdef-sd-h-considered-a-bad-practice?noredirect=1#comment219474_94743) because empirically, I know I make mistakes...